Hull and White (1987) stochastic volatility model in presence of nonzero correlation
I have done some research in Hull and White (1987) stochstic volatility model, where they have almost closed-form solution under zero correlation between the stock price and volatility.
I wonder if there are some literature investigating the situation when the correaltion between stock price and volatility are non-zero.
Please kindly tell me some studies people already done since I couldn't find them somewhere online.
J. C. Hull and A. White, The Pricing of Options on Assets with Stochastic Volatilities, The Journal of Finance, 1987, 42, 281-300

Their solution is not that "closed form". Numerical integration or Taylor expansion neglecting higher order terms. If you want "closed form" look at the SABR model. If you want full generality use a Monte Carlo simulation of stock and vol. Quite often this requires the least amount of code and the math involved is least cumbersome and error prone.
